# Selected Spinner data not appear

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

i have implemented Spinner, getting data of spinner from Server when selecting value from drop down list it does not Selected

```
    timeSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.snipper2);
        timeSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(singleDay.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dateArrayList));
        timeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(singleDay.this, "i am working...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(singleDay.this, ""+adapterView.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
String s=timeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                textView.setText(s);

            }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        Toast.makeText(singleDay.this, "i am working...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Xml code here:

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/snipper2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
                android:prompt="@string/spinnertitle"
                android:layout_width="129dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"

                />
```

screenshots attached below:

[image: After select nothing sleeted]

Comment: Does Toast show on onItemselected ?

Comment: no i think this method not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `spinner` `height` and `width`. It appears to be too small to display data.

Change your code to this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,dateArrayList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

timeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

You can use `getItemAtPosition()` method to get the selected item:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
final String itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Log.i("Item Selected: ", itemSelected);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Does dateArrayList have date in it?

Comment: Create a test ArrayList and see if it displays its data

Comment: data is display in my code but after selecting any list items it do not selected

Comment: can you attach screenshots with your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139497/discussion-between-mohit-singh-and-suhayl-sh).